# Video Ads for unity3d WebPlayer games

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, unity-web-player

I have a unity3d game published on facebook. Is it possible to implement rewarded video for that game? I tried to use some advertisement platforms for standalone web pages. I add their sdk as an injection from unity to fb canvas page, but they does not work correct and do not meet my needs. Which ad network you would try to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a rewarded video on facebook with supersonic.com